# Isomorphism class of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is a prime/maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to $\mathbb{\overline{Q}}$ the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. I've already shown that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is integrally closed and that every non-trivial prime ideal is maximal and that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is not Noetherian. I want to know what is the isomorphism class of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathcal{B}$ for a prime/maximal ideal $\mathcal{B}$. I believe it must be an infinite field but I can't really give any good candidates.

Comment: Over $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ every monic integer polynomial splits, thus so it does in $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathcal{B}$. If $\mathcal{B} \ni \alpha\ne 0$ then $\mathcal{B} \supset \alpha\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \ni N(\alpha)$ where $N(\alpha) = \# \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(\alpha)$. Thus  $N(\alpha) = 0$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathcal{B}$ so it has a positive characteristic $p$ and it contains a copy of $\overline{\mathbf{F}_p}$. It doesn't contain any transcendental element so $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathcal{B} \cong \overline{\mathbf{F}_p}$.

Comment: @reuns What determines p? Also, by $N(\alpha)$ do you mean norm?

Comment: $\mathcal{B}$ contains a positive integer, and since it is a prime ideal, it must contain one (and only one) prime $p$ (the least positive integer in $\mathcal{B}$). $N(\alpha) = \#\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\alpha \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ which must then belong to $\alpha \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and hence to $\mathcal{B}$.